# Как пишется байт переноса строки в C?

Tags: c

Здравствуйте, есть функция Serial.read() которая выдает информацию по байтам (я в C работаю первый раз так что может я и не прав), тип данных на выходе **char**, я хочу найти конец строки (строки разделены \r\n), т.е. сделать проверку:

```
if (Serial.read()== ...) { 
    // это конец строки
}
```

Что я должен вписать вместо **...**  что бы моя проверка сработала?

Comment: Вы упорно постите вопросы, не имеющий даже отдаленного отношения к языку С, под тэгом [C]. Это преднамеренный троллинг?

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно, что вы не можете проверить два байта с помощью лишь одного вызова функции, возвращающий один байт - так зачем пытаться? Читайте два байта и проверяйте.

Comment: Хорошо, допустим я буду записывать в отдельную константу прошлый байт, тем не менее это не меняет вопроса, я пытался сделать проверку (Serial.read()== (char) '\n'), но не помогло, как мне сверять их?

Comment: @GeneralProger проверка будет иметь не ту форму, что в вашем вопросе. Попробуйте сделать сначала, если не получится, то задайте вопрос с более конкретным кодом и описанием того, что вы пробовали.

Comment: Ну, а разница? Я допустим каждый байт записываю, если байт идет вторым в списке то из массива char cmd[128] мы достаем прошлый байт т.е. cmd[index] == Serial.read(); index++;  if ((index > 2) && (cmd[(index - 2)]== RBYTE && cmd[(index - 1)]== NBYTE)),  что должно быть в RBYTE и NBYTE что бы прошло сравнение требуемое?

Comment: @GeneralProger '\r' и '\n'. Байт = char

Comment: У файлов в текстовом режиме пара `\r\n` заменяется на `\n`. Что такое `Serial` и как он работает - неизвестно.

Comment: @Qwertiy заменяется только в Windows, современные никсы не различают текстовый и бинарный режимы

Comment: Да, я имел в виду windows. В линуксе же и так перевод строки принято через `\n` делать.

Comment: @Qwertiy не всегда, например в MIME по стандарту нужен `\r\n` (правда, все все равно понимают простой `\n`)